# Get the future timespec of the current time

Tags: c, portability, c11

I can get current time using the `timespec_get` C11 function. Supposedly I want to retrieve the timespec value of the next milliseconds of the current time, how should I write the `get_due_time` function?

```
struct timespec get_due_time(long ms) { 
    struct timespec now, due;
    timespec_get(&now, TIME_UTC);
    ...
    return due;
}
```

Comment: `value of the next milliseconds of the current time` what does that mean? A millisecond is a millisecond, no matter what time it is. You want to add a millisecond to the current time?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I'm trying to append a given amount of milliseconds to the `now` timespec that I get from it.

Comment: So just add one millisecond to the nanosecond field. Then if there are more nanoseconds then a second, increment seconds. Where exactly are you having a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct timespec get_due_time(long ms)
{
    assert(ms >= 0);
    struct timespec now, due;
    timespec_get(&now, TIME_UTC);
    due.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + ms / 1000;
    due.tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec + (ms % 1000) * 1000000;
    if (due.tv_nsec >= 1000000000)
    {
        due.tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
        due.tv_sec++;
    }
    return due;
}
```

Deal with big values of `ms` by adding whole seconds to the seconds part of the current time (there are 1000 milliseconds in a second).  Deal with the sub-second part of the value of `ms` by multiplying by one million (the number of nanoseconds in a millisecond).  Deal with overflow of `tv_nsec` by subtracting one billion (the number of nanoseconds in a second) from `tv_nsec` and incrementing the `tv_sec` part.  The arithmetic is safe assuming `timespec_get()` returns a normalized `struct timespec` value (so `tv_nsec` is in the range 0..999,999,999.

You could simply modify `now` and return it instead of creating and modifying `due`.  That's not a significant problem, though.

You could create and use names like:

```
enum
{
    MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000,
    NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND  = 1000000000,
    NANOSECONDS_PER_MILLISECOND = NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND / MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
};
```

I'm not sure whether that's worth it.

If you need to handle negative offsets (negative values for `ms`), you have more work to do, dealing with negative results `tv_nsec` after adding a negative quantity and decrementing `tv_sec` if necessary.